# Webpage what sending and receiving

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know what exactly a webpage requesting/sending to where and what it is receiving from. How can I know?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try Network tab in Developer Tools (F12) ?

Comment: [Telerik Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Comment: Yes I did, actually I downloaded a webpage which contains several javascript code. The page requesting for information to some website and reciving some data from I can look at javascript code already but I want all request and receives and I don't want to miss

Comment: Select `All` filter in Network tab, that should display everything - html, css, json, js, images etc.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it just now but I want something else. Here is the thing; there is a webpage which automatically updating by javascript, I downloaded this webpage and it stopped updating, I know this is because the webpage I'm downloaded is local now. I want to know what variables this page sending and what variables this page can't get and could not update itself on my local.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, and Safari all have some sort of Developer Tools built into them. I will talk about Google Chrome, but they all have similar functionality.

In Google Chrome, you can access the tools by hitting [Control]-[Shift]-[J]. The toolbox has a strip of tabs across the top. You want to access the Network tab. This screen will either contain a series of requests, or it will ask you to start recording (or something like this).

When your page loads, or whenever an AJAX request happens, a new entry will be added to this list. For example, loading a webpage will usually request the original html file, some CSS files, some of JavaScript files, and some images. The list will usually let you open each resource in a new tab or view more information about each request (such as whether or not it succeeded, what data was sent or received, and so on).

You can learn more about Chrome's Developer Tools here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: Thank you, I tried it just now but I want something else. Here is the thing; there is a webpage which automatically updating by javascript, I downloaded this webpage and it stopped updating, I know this is because the webpage I'm downloaded is local now. I want to know what variables this page sending and what variables this page can't get and could not update itself on my local.

Comment: @mhndlsz - have you tried running the Developer Tools against the live site? You can see each of the pages that the webpage is calling. There is a JavaScript debugger built into the Developer Tools that can help you analyze this also.

Answer (score 0):

You can view that with the Developer Tools in Chrome and Firefox. Open it with `F12` in Windows/Linux and `cmd+alt+i` in Mac.

Once there, you can view what you ask for in the "Network" tab.